# ":" Operator to Assign Integer

Tags: objective-c, c, integer

I was looking at the `UIViewController` header in Xcode, and I saw something that I have never encountered before. It was located in a `struct`, so I assume it was a member variable, but the way it was assigned was new to me. Here shortened version (the `struct` is 47 lines).

```
struct {
    unsigned int appearState:2;
    unsigned int isEditing:1;
    unsigned int isPerformingModalTransition:1;
    unsigned int hidesBottomBarWhenPushed:1;
    unsigned int autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize:1;
    // many more : assignments
} _viewControllerFlags;
```

Could someone shed some light on what `:` does? Is it like the C++ variable declaration syntax (`bool b(true);`), or something completely different? Possibly some reference type such as `*` and `&`.

Comment: Those are bitfields.  The value after the `:` is the number of bits occupied by the field.  All the fields fit together in one `int`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ':' allows assignment (and later reference) of individual bits, of the same (unsigned int).

```
appearState gets 2 bits,
```

Hence 'appearState' may contain values: 0, 1, 2 or 3 only.

```
isEditing gets 1 bit,
```

'isEditing' may contain values: 0 or 1 only.

```
...etc.
```